# Is it possible to measure temperature using sound?

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, acoustics

Is it possible to measure the temperature of something using sound, by blasting sound waves at solid objects, liquids and gasses, then measuring how much sound is reflected or absorbed, to give an accurate atmospheric measurement of temperature?

Comment: Elastically deforming the lattice introduces temperature fluctuations into the material...

however, if you are not interested in really accurate temperatures, perhaps you can get atmospheric or environmental temperature averages somehow..

Comment: So sonar-based thermometers?

Comment: @KyleKanos Indeed. Of great interest to the steelmaking and other industries where temperature profiles make a great deal of difference to the product but where measurement is challenging.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it possible to measure the temperature of something using sound...?

Yes, it is not only possible, it is available commercially.  It is especially useful in harsh environments where conventional temperature probes might not survive.

For example, [TMT](http://www.tmt.com/uk/docs/standard/page.cfm/TMT-SOMA-blast-furnace-gas-temperature-measurement_152.htm) makes an acoustic system for measuring 2-D temperature distributions in blast furnaces:

> The acoustic gas temperature measuring system TMT SOMA™ (SOMA stands
>   for Sonic Mapping) as described hereafter is able to provide a
>   complete and continuous 2D temperature distribution of the top gas
>   inside the blast furnace above the burden. The system is based on the
>   principle of acoustic gas temperature measurement sometimes also
>   referred to as "sonic pyrometry"…

TMT claims accuracy of  ± 2.5%.

Another company making acoustic temperature measurement systems is [SEI](http://www.sciengr.com/product.html).  Here is a schematic of their approach showing the ability to measure 2-D temperature profiles:

[image]

SEI claims an accuracy of better than 0.5%.

If you want to design your own system, Linear Technology Corporation makes integrated circuits to support your efforts.   Their [Application Note 131](http://cds.linear.com/docs/en/application-note/an131f.pdf) describes acoustic temperature measurement as follows:

> Acoustic thermometry is an arcane, elegant temperature measurement
>   technique. It utilizes sound’s temperature dependent transit time in a
>   medium to measure temperature. The medium may be a solid, liquid or
>   gas. Acoustic thermometers function in environments that conventional
>   sensors cannot tolerate.

Linear Technology quotes accuracies of 1°F or better.

Comment: I'm looking for accurate measurements where temperatures reach higher than 2000K+ so does your original answer of yes still apply?

Comment: @Bonner The TMT system is spec'd for a temperature range of [0 to 2000°C](http://www.tmt.com/uk/docs/standard/page.cfm/TMT-SOMA-blast-furnace-gas-temperature-measurement_152.htm) which would include 2000K and more.  So, yes.

Comment: Interesting. A long time ago I worked for the research labs of a steelmaking / mining company, and we vaguely got these ideas working for steel blooms (much lower temperature): we were more after acoustic tomography seeking faults and flaws in the casting. Very interesting to see similar things commercialized thirty years later. What is your background? Those transducers must be quite a feat of packaging technology to withstand the inside of a blast furnace.

Comment: @WetSavannaAnimalakaRodVance Yes, the thermal packaging is impressive.  So, is the tomography software.  (My background includes some research on temperature sensing for high-Temperature and hostile conditions but not this particular technology.)

Answer (score 0):

In principle, you could detect changes on the speed of sound when passing between different zones of a fluid which have different thermodynamic conditions (i.e. different temperature and pressure as well, or density). Indeed sound propagates differently in the same fluid when different temperature, pressure or density, or any combination of them is present.

But when passing through interfaces, i.e. gas to liquid or gas/liquid to solid, I would say the reflection of sound is much more intense and would be harder to understand.

Now the question if all this is really feasible, I guess you would get it if you try, maybe there is some way but it sure would require some study. There is normally a big difference between the theoretical possibility, and the actual possibility of understanding, classifying and quantifying some magnitudes from how other influence them.